# A single idiom or phrase that means " I didn't feel sleepy anymore"

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

Is there any idiom/phrase that convey this meaning: "**someone or something caused me not to feel sleepy anymore at a specific moment or situation"?**

Please read these scenarios:

1. Last night ​​I was sound asleep when the telephone rang. I coudn't sleep again after that and lay awake until morning.
2. Suppose you have an exam tomorrow, and you haven't finished reviewing your book yet. Now you feel so sleepy that you decide to rinse/wash your face with cold water in order to remove (?) that sleepy feeling.
3. While you are going to your work by bus, you feel so drowsy that take a short nap, but a loud cry breaks (?) your nap, and you don't feel drowsy any more!

I have found these idioms and phrases by googling:

- Somebody or something made me awake
- I was wide awake
- I washed the sleep out of my face
- I couldn't get back to sleep

Actually, I'm looking for a single idiom, or phrase that *can be used in all those situations I illustrated in my examples.*

Comment: I think the ones you found are pretty much perfect. It's usually "I was sleepy/sleeping/feeling drowsy but now I'm wide awake."

Comment: Thanks, Mari-Luo A. I specially like " wash the sleep out of my face" , but I coudn't find it any reliable sources ( dictionaries) on Internet.

Comment: Would roused be suitable? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/roused

Answer (score 3):

***To feel [wakeful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wakeful)*** conveys the meaning you are referring to:

> - not sleeping or not able to sleep.
> - unable or unwilling to sleep.

The Free Dictionary

From [Solve Your Child's Sleep Problems](https://books.google.it/books?id=soY1FV4ft8cC&pg=PT163&dq=%22feel%20wakeful%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMI8LGkk5DnyAIVAW8UCh0jIgUG#v=onepage&q=%22feel%20wakeful%22&f=false):

> - .... when *you feel wakeful* and get up when you want to sleep.

From [Get Fit, Feel Fantastic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FZxQfLlfsEIC&q=%22feel%20wakeful%22&dq=%22feel%20wakeful%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwA2oVChMI8LGkk5DnyAIVAW8UCh0jIgUG):

> - If your body does not produce enough melatonin during the evening, *you will still feel wakeful* at bedtime and have difficulty sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

Consider. *I was [brought or shaken or pulled] [**out of my torpor**](https://www.google.com.br/#tbm=bks&q=%22out+of+my+torpor%22)*.

> torpor: a state of mental or physical inactivity or insensibility [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/torpor)